# Determine movement vector's direction from velocity

Tags: javascript, vector, 2d, angle

I'm kinda confused with this one.

I have an object and I know it's velocities on axis x and y. My problem is how to determine the angle at which it's moving.

```
function Object(){
    this.velocity = {x: 5, y: 1};
}
```

Basically I Know that a vector's direction is x_projection*cos(deg) + y_projection*sin(deg), but I don't know how to get those projections since I only have the velocity, as I said I'm really confused.

#EDIT:

in addition to the accepted answer, here's what I did to get a full 360 degree spectrum

```
var addDeg = 0;
if(obj.velocity.x<0)
    addDeg = obj.velocity.y>=0 ? 180 : 270;
else if(obj.velocity.y<=0) addDeg = 360;

deg = Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.atan(obj.velocity.y/obj.velocity.x)*180/Math.PI)-addDeg)
```

Comment: Whats your reference axis?

Comment: I don't really know what that is. How I see it is just the object has 360 degrees of potential directions to move at, I want to get the one it's actually moving at. Like if the velocity is x:1, y:1 and the coordinate system starts from the top left corner and y increments downwards in a positive manner, then the direction would be 45 degrees

Comment: Like if you start drawing a circle from the center of the object counter-clockwise, that's how the degrees go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know how to get those projections since I only have the
>   velocity

Actually, what you seem to be missing is that you already have the projections. That's what x and y are.

x *is* speed * cos(angle)

y *is* speed * sin(angle)

So y/x = sin(angle)/cos(angle) which is tan(angle) so angle=arctan(y/x).

That's the angle rotating anti-clockwise starting from the x axis (with x pointing right and y pointing up).

Comment: Actually this only gives me 0 to 90 degree in each quadrant, I need a full 360 degree specter

Comment: With a little tweaking I got it working, I'll post what I did in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Find the angle between that vector and (1,0) (Right horizontal positive direction).

The math is:

A = (5,1)
B = (1,0)

A.B = |A||B|cos(angle) -> angle = arccos((|A||B|)/(A.B))

[Dot product, check geometric definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Edit:

Another option is to use the cross product formula:

|AxB| = |A||B|sin(angle) -> angle = arcsin((|A||B|)/(|AxB|))

It will give you the angle you need.

Comment: It seems that I'm retarded.. I can't understand what to put in the places of A and B :<

Comment: A is your example vector, and B the axis you will have to find the angle. It's the angle between A and B. Check the wikipedia link. You are not retarded, you just dont know about vectors at all it seems.

Comment: I am looking at it, but I'm confused because these are vectors and I only have scalar expressions in javascript. In order to represent a vector in a scalar environment I know that it's a sum between it's two projections ( for 2d ), but to get the projections I need the angle I'm looking for ( or the opposite one ). As you can probably see my head is a mess. I'm gonna continue reading and hope for the best

Comment: Just do the math I presented you, replacing A.B by (A.x*B.x + A.y*B.y), |A| by the vector length (sqrt(A.x^2 + A.y^2)) and |B| by the vector length |B| by the vector length (sqrt(B.x^2 + B.y^2)).

Comment: I did it and it only gives me 0 and 180, other angles give me NaN ( Not a Number )

Comment: It should work for all angles between 0 and 180. Also, there is the problem of orthogonal vectors that makes the denominator 0. You should use the cross product formula, not that one. I suggest you to use a library that has all this functions available to you. I use THREE.js to handle some of the vector calculations for me, but I believe there are other libs that will better suit you.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is build my own, well library is a little exaggerated. These formulas seem pretty complicated, I don't know how to represent vectors in arithmetic like |AxB|. I solved the issue using atan, suggested in another answer. Thank you for your time and effort, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to get full 360 degrees. What you're looking for, is `Math.atan2`:

```
deg = Math.atan2(obj.velocity.y,obj.velocity.x)*180/Math.PI;
```